# I need webp image on Opencart 3. It is possible?

Tags: image, opencart

Is it possible to use webp images in opencart 3? I mean automatic generation.

Answer (score 2):

Not all the browsers accept WEBP image format
but you can type a code to check if the browser accept WEBP format then you will have to make a new images cache and convert the existing images to webp

on the fir dir catalog/model/tool/image.php
add

```
$image_new_webp = 'cachewebp/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . (int)$width . 'x' . (int)$height . '.webp';
```

after this

```
 $image_new = 'cache/'
```

to check if the browser accept image.webp and to create your new images cache
in the same file: catalog/model/tool/image.php
add this code:

```
$gd = gd_info();
        if ($gd['WebP Support']) {
            if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp) || (filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp))) {
                                    
                $path = '';

                $directories = explode('/', dirname($image_new_webp));

                foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                    $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                    if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                        @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                    }
                }
                
                $image_webp = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $image_old);
                $image_webp->resize($width, $height);
                $image_webp->save_webp(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new_webp);
            }
        }
```

before this line: `$image_new = str_replace(`

now you need a function to save the images in new format
on file dir: system/library/image.php
add this function:

```
public function save_webp($file, $quality = 90) {
            if (is_resource($this->image)) {
                imagewebp($this->image, $file, $quality);
                imagedestroy($this->image);
            }
        }
```

before this line: `public function save($file, $quality = 90) {`

output the webp images format
add this function on file system/library/response.php

```
public function webpRebuild($output) {
            $gd = gd_info();
            if ($gd['WebP Support']) {
                $uri = '';

                if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
                    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                }
                
                if (stripos($uri, 'admin') === false) { // admin is your dashboard url if you have different name jst change it  
                    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                        if( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp' ) !== false ) {   
                            $re = '/(cache)(.*)(\.jpg|\.png|.jpeg)/U';
                            $subst = '$1webp$2.webp';
                            $this->output = preg_replace($re, $subst, $this->output);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

before this line: `private function compress($data, $level = 0)`
on the same file you have to output the webpRebuild function so add this code:

```
$this->webpRebuild($this->output);
```

after this line: `$output = $this`

Comment: Thank you, I am using this solution and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Search the OpenCart extension marketplace for "webp":
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=webp

Here are a couple, both free:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=36308
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=34275

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is at [Design Cart](https://www.designcart.pl). The extension generates additional webp images and displays them if the user's browser supports webp. [Download](https://www.designcart.pl/laboratorium/1-dc-webp-images.html).