# How can i fix Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) errors in search console

Tags: css, responsive, opencart2.x, google-search-console, cumulative-layout-shift

i have a website [indiabazaaronline.com](https://www.indiabazaaronline.com) that shows Cumulative Layout Shift(CLS) issue >.25 errors in google search console. Due to this we recently lost 50% organic impressions and click. i have no idea how this will be fixed. Any clue or tutorial that will lead to fixing this issue will be highly appreciated. I tried removing the sticky navigation header but still the same error is there.

Answer (score 1):

Specify width and height in your images and remove the propety loading="lazy" if you have it. That work good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Minify `JS` and `CSS` you can find it here :[matthiasmullie | minify](https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify)

and for the images you can change the images format to `WEBP` if you don't know how follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439288/7660119

Answer (score 0):

There is no one right answer to improving CLS. Rather, you need to run a page speed test and address issues unique to your site.

1. Test your site with Google Page Speed Insights: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Findiabazaaronline.com%2F
2. Click on each "Opportunity" and address any specific recommendations.
3. Below the "View Tree Map" select "Show Audits Relevant to: CLS" and address any specific recommendations. Selecting "Avoid Large Layout Shifts" for example identifies which DOM elements specifically are causing your layout to shift.